# nodejs: http content not transferred full

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
express = require('express');

app.get("/proxy*", function (request, response) {

    options = {
        host: rmHost,
        port: 4000,
        path: request.originalUrl,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            secure: false
        }
    };
    console.log(request.originalUrl);
    http.get(options, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        resp.on('data', function(chunk)    {
            data += chunk;
        });

        resp.on('end', () => {
            response.write(data);
            response.end()
        });
    }).on("error", (err) => {
        response.write("Error: " + err.message);
    });
});
```

Content is not transferred to the client full getting following errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js:1

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token > 
< jquery.dataTables.min.js:1

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

> test.dt.plugins.js:18

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

> ```
> at test.dt.plugins.js:18 RUNNING:38
> ```

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

> ```
> at RUNNING:38 RUNNING:53
> ```

Comment: How does your client code look like? Are you sure the syntax error is not in the html or test code ?